# Stop, upgrade, start all Docker Stack services together?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-stack

I'd like to stop all services in my `docker-stack.yml` file, update the file with new image version numbers, and then start all services. In order to upgrade them all together, so that they're always all of them at the very latest version.

How do I do this? I'd rather not delete networks and volumes — I mean, `docker stack rm` seems like overkill? And `docker service scale service-name=0` feels error prone? then one needs to remember to change back to > 0 again.

The reason I want to do a stop-everything upgrade, is that it's simpler: The services in my app then won't need to be compatible with different versions of each other's APIs. There'll never be version X of a service running and having to communicate with version X - 1 of another service (instead, all services will be on the same version X. They use the same version numbers).

(And feel free to let me know if I'm asking the wrong question :- )  Note: In this particular case, 20 - 30 seconds downtime because all containers stop-upgrade-restart at once, is okay. And this is for Docker Swarm / Stack, not Docker-Compose (then one could just do `down` and `up`). )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I feel like this is the wrong approach to upgrades. It introduces downtime into a system that's designed to be highly available.

---

To stop a service, I'd probably add a constraint that cannot be satisfied, e.g.

```
docker service update \
  --constraint-add node.label.disable_service==true -d \
  ${service_name}
```

This covers both replicated and globally scheduled services. When you redeploy a stack using a compose file, it will remove this constraint (it should also remove any scale changes).

---

If your stack is as tightly coupled as you describe, something close to a blue/green deployment may be a better option. Put a proxy in front of your services attached to two docker networks, and start your blue or green stack on one of those networks. Then to replace it, start the other stack on the other network, and once running and the proxy is routing traffic, stop the first stack.

Comment: This means that the service may only run on nodes with the label `disable_service==true`? Which is zero nodes because no nodes have this "weird" label? So therefore all instances of the service, will shut down? (they have no where to "live") — Thanks for the tips about blue green. Actually, that'd be overkill for 99% ? of the organizations that use the software. It's open source software for communication, and one minute downtime when upgrading maybe once a month, is fine :- )

Comment: @KajMagnus that's correct, the service will fail to schedule on any nodes as long as you set the constraint to an unused label.

Comment: Hmm: *"It introduces downtime into a system that's designed to be highly available."* — well, that a system is designed for HA, doesn't mean that HA is needed or that one should try to make use of it. One doesn't need to make use of all features and benefits a system has. For example, if a car is ... designed to be able to go 200 kmph, ... that doesn't mean I need to strive for going 200 kmph when driving :- ) I can go in just 30kmph and if the car is for free and has other benefits that make it a great car in my case, then, it can still be the right car.

Comment: Ok thanks for explaining :- ) Now I accepted the answer.

Comment: I like this approach better than `... scale ... 0`, because I don't need to remember to scale back the service to the previous number of instances. Instead I'll just remove the label.

Comment: @KajMagnus when you deploy your stack file again (with your updates), there's no need to remove the label or change the scale because the originally values (or no value at all) is defined in that stack file and redeployed.